# How to calculate this definite integral :- $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{a^2\cos^2x + b^2\sin^2x} \,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This question was in a test I took: calculate the value of the integral $$\int_0^\pi \dfrac{x}{a^2\cos^2x + b^2\sin^2x} \,dx.$$

I was not able to solve it. Now, I've tried to do some substitutions for $x$ but honestly I don't actually know how to proceed with this integral.

As I have not solved such questions before, I don't know the general direction in which I need to go so I don't know which efforts to include here and which to not.

All I know is that those constants *a* & *b* are the source of much of the trouble for me but I don't know how to get rid of them.

I also want to know whether there is only a single way to solve it (which maybe I've not practised enough) or - like many other problems - it can be solved by more than one method.

I would really appreciate if I find different solutions of this problem here but (if you can help it) please don't include any incredibly tough/ esoteric theorems or concepts/ higher-level stuff that I can't be expected to know at my current level. Thanks!

Comment: can we assume that $$a,b>0$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I don't think it was explicitly given in the question. But I am interested, why is that important?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner One can at least assume that $a=|a|$ and $b=|b|$ for sure.

Comment: The definite integral is $\frac{\pi ^2}{2 a b}$
The indefinite integral is VERY difficult! https://tinyurl.com/ybzu5492

Comment: @Raffaele, how did you get the solution for the definite integral so quickly?

Comment: *Mathematica* 10

Answer (score 9):

Use $\int _a^b f (x)=\int _a^b f (a+b-x ) \, dx $ to get $2I=\int _a^b \frac {\pi}{a^2\cos^2 (x)+b^2\sin^2 (x)} \,dx $ now take $\cos^2 (x) $ common and let $\tan (x)=t $ thus $\sec^2 (x) \, dx=dt $ hope you can continue with basic integral from here.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow how you got $2I=\int _a^b \frac {\pi}{a^2\cos^2 (x)+b^2\sin^2 (x)}$ from the given property.

Comment: Where it says "take $\cos^2 x$ common", I think it means write $$ \frac \pi {a^2\cos^x + b^2\sin^2 x} \, dx = \left( \frac \pi { a^2 + b^2 \frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x} }\right) \left( \frac{dx}{\cos^2 x} \right) $$ and then $\sin^2 x/\cos^2 x$ becomes $\tan^2 x$ and $dx/\cos^2 x = \sec^2 x\, dx = d(\tan x). \qquad$

Comment: See we have $I=\int _a^b f (x)dx=\int_a^b (\frac {\pi}{a^2cos^2 (x)+b^2sin^2 (x)}-\frac{x}{a^2cos^2 (x)+b^2sin^2 (x)}dx $ now see that the part in front of minus is f (x) $ hence the result.

Comment: make the substitution $x = \pi - u$ and simplify and you will get that $\int_0^\pi \frac {x}{a^2\cos^2 x + b^2\sin^2 x} \ dx = \int_0^\pi \frac {\pi - u}{a^2\cos^2 u + b^2\sin^2 u} \ du$

Comment: @MrReality : ok, Now I think I see what your question is. Look at "Doug M" 's comment. Add together then two integrals asserted to be equal to each other in that comment. Each is equal to $I,$ so their sum is $2I. \qquad$

Comment: @Archis, I got that now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome @ Mr Reality.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael for the help!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\pi \frac x {a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \, dx = I \\[10pt]
& \int_0^\pi \frac x {a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \, dx = \int_0^\pi \frac {\pi-x} {a^2\cos^2(\pi-x)+b^2\sin^2(\pi-x)} \, dx \\[10pt]
I = {} & \int_0^\pi \frac{\pi-x}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\pi \frac \pi {a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \, dx - I \\[10pt]
2I = {} & \frac 1 {a^2} \int_0^\pi \frac{\pi\sec^2 x}{1 + \left( \frac b a \tan x \right)^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \left. \frac \pi {ab} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac b a \tan x \right) \right|_0^\pi
\end{align}

[image]
The answer using the famous identity

Comment: The answer cannot be $0$, as the integrand is positive over the range of integration...

Comment: you can use that $\frac  {\sec^2 x}{a^2 + b^2 \tan^2 x}$ is symmetric about the line $x = \frac {\pi}{2}$  so $\int_0^{\pi} \frac {\pi \sec^2 x}{a^2 + b^2\tan^2 x} \ dx = 2\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\pi \sec^2 x}{a^2 + b^2\tan^2 x} \ dx \implies I = \frac {\pi^2}{2|ab|}$

Comment: And to note why the $0$ answer was wrong : the FTC doesn't hold if there is a discontinuity in the domain of integration.

Comment: Where the dicontinuity in the domain of integration ?

Comment: @HussienMohamed : It is at $x=\pi/2,$ where the tangent and secant have a vertical asymptote. One could consider them continuous there by taking their value to be $\infty,$ construing that not as $+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ but as a single $\infty$ at both ends of the line, but one must exam the conditions under which this way of proceeding is valid. Otherwise your method looks good, although I'd be more explicit about explaining some of the details.

Comment: @Michael Hardy .The original integrand does not include the neither the tangent nor the secant function !

Comment: @HussienMohamed : That is true, but the form into which you put it does. And the form of the original integrand should tell you to expect a positive number.

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed, yes, peter and Michael are right, your answer is incorrect. As Doug said, the correct answer is $ \frac  {{\pi}^2}{2ab}$.

Comment: Yes , i got it i would use the improper integration to evaluate the right hand side